# Button with MahApps style show only lower case latters

Tags: wpf, button, mahapps.metro

This is my Button:

```
<Button
    Name="btnOk"
    Content="OK"
    Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"/>
```

And the `content` is always with lower case latter when using this `Style`

Comment: Show Style definition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use

`Controls:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"`

to prevent lower case (or upper case on other controls).

**EDIT**

There is a change in the Alpha release (the upcoming v1.2.0). It's now possible to change the case much more easier.

```
<!-- possible values are: Normal, Upper and Lower -->
Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Normal"
```

Comment: how to apply Controls:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True" on a button?

Comment: Add **xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"** to your namespace declarations and add that property to your button. **<Button  Controls:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"/>**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with with @punker76 as in version v1.2.0 and now the latest v2.4.7, you can only use

```
<!-- possible values are: Normal, Upper and Lower -->
Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Normal"
```

If you'd like to use it as a property, you can use this like this

```
Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal"
```